In FreshRSS, how to mark articles before yesterday as read in the filter?
How to mark articles before yesterday as read in the filter，I tried date:P1D/, date:/P1D, date:/P-1D，but it didn't work. Here are the rules:
https://freshrss.github.io/FreshRSS/en/users/10_filter.html#with-the-search-field

By date of discovery, using the ISO 8601 time interval format: date:<date-interval>


Before a given date: date:/2014-03

Can anyone help me? Thank you!
